# Ubuntu Chrome I cannot resize window

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Chrome v. 30 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I've been trying to resize a tab so that I can have two windows open side by side. But there are no maximize minimize buttons or menu item. How do I do this?

---

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Added a screen shot. What do you mean by "window decorations"?